Clone git repository and install python packages in a shared folder path
I have a python project in a git repository and I am creating an azure pipeline to do the following tasks for that project:

If git repository does not exist on a shared folder path, then clone it, else pull the last code.
If virtual environment folder (.venv) does not exist on a shared folder path, then create and activate the virtual environment, else activate the current environment.
Install python packages located in the file requirements.txt

This is my current YAML file to reach the previous steps:
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  name: 'On Premise Windows'
  demands: Agent.Name -equals [Agent_name]

variables:
- group: Variable_Group
- name: PAT
  value: $[variables.PAT]

steps:
- checkout: self
  displayName: 'Checkout Repository'

- powershell: |
    $parent_folder = '\\server\my\shared\folder\path'
    $target_folder = Join-Path -Path $parent_folder -ChildPath '[project_name]'
    $target_folder_exists = Test-Path -Path $target_folder
    if ($target_folder_exists) {
      cd $target_folder
      git pull
    } else {
      git clone 'https://$(PAT)@dev.azure.com/my/git/project' $parent_folder
    }
  enabled: True
  displayName: 'Clone or Pull Git repository'

- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.11'

- powershell: |
    $parent_folder = '\\server\my\shared\folder\path\[project_name]'
    $target_folder = Join-Path -Path $parent_folder -ChildPath '.venv'
    &requirements_path = Join-Path -Path $parent_folder -ChildPath 'requirements.txt'
    $target_folder_exists = Test-Path -Path $target_folder
    if ($target_folder_exists) {
      cd &parent_folder
      & C:\"Program Files"\Python311\python.exe -m venv .venv
    }
    pip install -r $requirements_path
  displayName: 'Setup Python Environment and Install Dependencies'

The agent I am using is intalled On-Premise server and my shared folder path is located in an Azure VM. I am getting the following error:

========================== Starting Command Output =========================== "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo
-NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". '....'" fatal:
could not create leading directories of
'\server\my\shared\folder\path':
No such file or directory
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'. Finishing: Clone or Pull Git repository

It seems the On-premise server must have access to that shared folder path. Therefore, I have the following questions:

Could On-premise server have access to the shared folder path if I give an user which has access to it? if so, how should I pass the user and password to access that path?. If not, what should be the proper way to achieve it?
Is powershell a good approach to clone my repository and then to install the python packages? If not, what would be the rigth approach?


Commands run as whatever user your agent's service is running as. If you change the agent to run as an account with access to the file share, that will automatically authenticate. However, I question why you're using a file share at all. What purpose does the file share serve, in your view?

Hi @sergioMoreno, have you got a chance to check if the answers work? Please try to change your self-hosted agent service account to the on that have access to the shared folder.

As the folder path is located in an Azure VM, you can consider configuring a self-hosted agent on the Azure VM. This way, you can directly access the folder and do what you need in the pipeline.
If you still want to access the shared folder path from the On-premise server, you can first try to run the PowerShell script on your On-premise server locally and manually. This is to check if it works and if your account has access to the file share.
You can run the following script to start the PowerShell to run as the user you want to use. In the new PowerShell session, you can run  whoami  to check the user you are using.
$username = ""
$password = ""
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $securePassword)

start powershell -credential $credential

If it works in local, you can configure your self-hosted agent service run as the account you are using in the above step. Then you can run the PowerShell script in the pipeline.

When using a self-hosted agent to run the pipeline, if you want the pipeline can directly access the shared folder from the agent machine, you need to set the agent service to logon with the account that can access the shared folder from the machine machine:

Manually logon the agent machine and open Services on the machine.

Find the agent service you need to use. Open its Properties.

On the Properties window, go to "Log On" tab and select "This account:". Then provide the username (domain\username) and password that can logon the agent machine and has the access to the shared folder.




If you cannot changes the logon account of the agent service, you can try to use the PowerShellOnTargetMachines@3 task in your pipeline.
On this task, you can:

Provide the username and password that can logon the remote machine which the shared folder is from.

Provide the PowerShell script to clone/pull the git repository and create/activate the virtual environment. Or other PowerShell script you might need to run on the remote machine.


When the task is running, it will use the username and password to logon the remote machine, and then run the PowerShell script on the remote machine.

